# Error querying database after uninstallation + reinstallation: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, database, next.js, access-denied

I get an error when querying my database after deleting my old version of MySQL and reinstalling the newest one.

I am using:
MySQL Ver 8.0.23 for macos10.15

My app is in Next.js and it was working fine before this. I'm running it on localhost. It uses serverless-mysql to connect:

```
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')

const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  }
})
```

The test connection works perfectly fine in MySQL Workbench.

Things I've tried:

- Resetting the password.
- Uninstalling MySQL again and using the Legacy Password Encryption. This makes the plugin for the root user "mysql_native_password".
- Creating a new user, granting them all permissions, and trying with their credentials

This might be overkill but here is what the user looks like after all of this:

COMMAND:

```
use mysql;
select * from user where User="root";
```

RESULT:

```
[
    {
        "Host" : "localhost",
        "User" : "root",
        "Select_priv" : "Y",
        "Insert_priv" : "Y",
        "Update_priv" : "Y",
        "Delete_priv" : "Y",
        "Create_priv" : "Y",
        "Drop_priv" : "Y",
        "Reload_priv" : "Y",
        "Shutdown_priv" : "Y",
        "Process_priv" : "Y",
        "File_priv" : "Y",
        "Grant_priv" : "Y",
        "References_priv" : "Y",
        "Index_priv" : "Y",
        "Alter_priv" : "Y",
        "Show_db_priv" : "Y",
        "Super_priv" : "Y",
        "Create_tmp_table_priv" : "Y",
        "Lock_tables_priv" : "Y",
        "Execute_priv" : "Y",
        "Repl_slave_priv" : "Y",
        "Repl_client_priv" : "Y",
        "Create_view_priv" : "Y",
        "Show_view_priv" : "Y",
        "Create_routine_priv" : "Y",
        "Alter_routine_priv" : "Y",
        "Create_user_priv" : "Y",
        "Event_priv" : "Y",
        "Trigger_priv" : "Y",
        "Create_tablespace_priv" : "Y",
        "ssl_type" : "",
        "ssl_cipher" : ?,
        "x509_issuer" : ?,
        "x509_subject" : ?,
        "max_questions" : 0,
        "max_updates" : 0,
        "max_connections" : 0,
        "max_user_connections" : 0,
        "plugin" : "mysql_native_password",
        "authentication_string" : "*E7CF5215B32CCDA122352F3A92E9F73131E28662",
        "password_expired" : "N",
        "password_last_changed" : "2021-02-24 18:54:52",
        "password_lifetime" : null,
        "account_locked" : "N",
        "Create_role_priv" : "Y",
        "Drop_role_priv" : "Y",
        "Password_reuse_history" : null,
        "Password_reuse_time" : null,
        "Password_require_current" : null,
        "User_attributes" : null
    }
]
```

Would really appreciate any help anyone can offer, this bug is destroying my sanity. Let me know if I can provide any more details.

Comment: Please provide your mysql configuration values with the sensitive data redacted. What version did you uninstall? Did you delete the `datadir` and start from scratch or did you skip the [mysql_upgrade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-what-is-upgraded.html)? What values are being supplied for `process.env.*`?

Comment: MYSQL_HOST = "localhost"
MYSQL_USER = "root"
MYSQL_DATABASE = "redacted"
MYSQL_PASSWORD = "redacted”
MYSQL_PORT = "3306"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just downloaded mySQL again. I don't know exactly the version I uninstalled, but I downloaded it in 2020. The version I'm currently working with is 8.0.23. I just redownloaded MySQL and used Legacy Password Encryption to see if that would help -- same exact error. All permissions granted. Work connecting via Workbench. I followed this guide to delete it: https://vivasart.com/en/lab/how-completely-remove-mysql-mac-osx. Tried my best to start from scratch.

Comment: Please DO NOT put solutions to questions in the question itself. If you managed to solve the problem then please post it as an answer to the question and not as an edit. This will help us see it has been solved as you can mark it as the solution which will pop up in the searches. Additionally once you do put the solution in an answer please do not put a solved tag in the title.

Comment: Thanks everyone -- just edited the post

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this problem was I manually entered my password in my code instead of the ENV file. It worked. When I console logged the ENV file to see why that wasn't working, it was because I was putting it in a string, for ex: MYSQL_PASSWORD = "password". It SHOULD be: MYSQL_PASSWORD = password

So if anyone is struggling, check that the ENV variables are set up correctly, and manually put them in to rule out any ENV issues.